# Fixing Handlebars compile issue in isomorphic JS app

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js, isomorphic-javascript

I'm turning an existing web app into isomorphic.
I've created a proof of a concept to play around with the dependencies that you can check [here](https://github.com/janoist1/isomjs-poc). The issue is: Handlebars `compile()` behaves different on the server and on the client side because of the templates are required/imported differently on these platform.

```
var view = require('someView.hbs');
var data = {};
var content = isServer ? view(data) : handlebars.compile(view)(data);
```

In the existing app I'd need to rewrite a lot of code by injecting the condition above .. Is there a better way to unify this, get rid of the condition? How to make the templates imported the same way on both sides?

Some more info:

- I use stringify: `require('stringify')`
- If I run `handlebars.compile(view)(data)` on the server side I get the following error:

> Error: You must pass a string or Handlebars AST to Handlebars.compile. You passed function ret(context, execOptions) {
>       if (!compiled) {
>         compiled = compileInput();
>       }
>       return compiled.call(this, context, execOptions);
>     }

Comment: Is there a way to customise the stringify logic that imports the templates in order to make them look the same like they do on the client side?

Answer (score 0):

If this `isServer ? view(data) : handlebars.compile(view)(data)` is working for you everywhere, you could create a function

```
var my_render = function(view,data) {
  return isServer ? view(data) : handlebars.compile(view)(data);
}
```

and then put `content = my_render(view,data)` where you need.

---

Perhaps a better solution is:

```
var my_compiled_hb = isServer ? view : handlebars.compile(view);
```

and then use `content = my_compiled_hb(data)` where you need.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but in the first round I try not to mix up things like having platform dependency in the templating logic. I'd imagine there was a way to `require` the templates the same way on both sides.